# How can I include a drag and drop interactive UI in jsp page?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags, jsplumb

I created a JSP page consisting of two tables and the page refreshes automatically after 5 second interval.On retrieval ,it fetches some data from the database using Java back end class and displays the required fields in the tables(both of them) with up to time information.A blank row will be created automatically in the table 1 depending upon the "flag" column's value(is a column of fetched table) fetched from the database.I want the user to be given with a privilege ,to "drag and drop" certain row from the table no:2 to table no:1 into this created blank row.The updated table should be shown instantly.Any suggestions please of where to start or what should be done to achieve this.

Comment: please share first your trial code! don't expect whole application programming answer for single question!

Comment: Yaa, will include right now.It was my idea.I have to implement it.I thought ,if I could get an idea for it,I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use
http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ 
http://jqueryui.com/droppable/
The row element should be draggable. 
The second table should be droppable.